# Bootstrap 2 rows, 1 column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new in bootstrap and stuck in next thing:
Using bootstrap grid, I need this thing [Bootstrap example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28448160/bootstrap-two-rows-on-the-left-and-one-on-the-right), but with some addings:
1) I need two columns (column 3),still having column 1 and 2
2)Width of column 1 and 2 - 20% and for first column 3 - width 20%, second column 3 - 60%
3)Do it using bootstrap, to have space between columns
Example: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzPRF.png).
Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by `need two columns (column 3)` ?? you want 2 or 3 columns?

Comment: There is column, named "Column 3", so I need two columns named "Column 3"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code may help you

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2" style="width: 20%">
            <div class="row">
                COLUMN 1
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                COLUMN 2
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2" style="width: 20%">
            COLUMN 3
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-7" style="width: 60%">
            COLUMN 3
        </div>
    </div>
```

Bootstrap grid system divides row in 12 columns you can achieve width according to it. You have to add extra css for exact 20 or 40% width.

Change style attr to class, add min-height and define css rules if required.

Comment: still columns ("Column 3") are on the same row, as Column 1. When I try to add style="width:20% " blocks aren't the same size.

Comment: ohh you want col1 & 2 with 20-20% width on row1, col3 with 40% on row2 and col4 with 40% on row3 ??

Comment: I was forced to change block's width, sorry, Columns 1 and 2 - 20%, first column 3 - 20% second column 3 - 60%.